# Q/Kdb: Combining two columns to create a new column as list

Tags: kdb

I needed a help in creating a new column as a list using two pre-existing column

```
CcyPair, Amount1, Amount2 
USDJPY   1666     2400
EURUSD   2344     3000
```

I want new output as

```
CcyPair, Amount1, Amount2, NewAmount
USDJPY   1666     2400     1666 2400
EURUSD   2344     3000     2344 3000
```

I tried doing 
    Select CcyPair,Amount1,Amount2,NewAmount:(Amount1;Amount2) 
    from table

but getting length error

Any ideas how this can be resolved.
Thanks

Comment: creating your table with: ```t:([]CcyPair:`USDJPY`EURUSD;Amount1:1666 2344;Amount2:2400 3000)```. I can run your query fine without encountering a length error.(albeit the output isn't what you are after- adding ```NewAmount:flip (Amount1;Amount2)```)should succeed. If you run meta table what does it return? Also is it a splayed table or just created in-memory? This should help determine cause of length error.

Comment: Thinking further, I imagine the most likely cause of your length error is because the actual table is larger than the example of 2 rows. It just happens that your query succeeds with a 2 row table as  (Amount1;Amount2) is a 2 itemed list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an update statement is what you want here.

Try:

```
update NewAmount:flip(Amount1;Amount2) from table
```

You can read more about update statements here:
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/#95-the-update-template

Answer (score 3):

You should use `,'` operator, which works like "pairwise" append.
Please, note, that in `update` or `select` statements it must be surrounded with brackets, otherwise comma will be misinterpreted by `q-slq`

```
t: ([]CcyPair: `USDJPY`EURUSD; Amount1: 1666 2344; Amount2: 2400 3000);
t: update NewAmount: (Amount1,'Amount2) from t;
t
```

Comment: This will likely be the best solution for joining two columns at scale, and is the best solution to the question. When joining multiple columns, Josh's answer will perform far better

Comment: Hi @Callum. Yes, you are right. Using `flip` is faster than pairwise concatenation, as it produces much less intermediate results.